# Git - How to get out to my master branch from REBASE 1/7 situation

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase

I was trying to experiment with merge stuff and I somehow ended up in the following scenarios. All I want is to go back to the tip of my master branch. What else other command can I try? I have tried 'git checkout master' but the "REBASE 1/7" label does not go away. 'blockurls' is another branch of mine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git rebase --abort`, then switch branches as usual.